# How do I estimate $\int_{2}^{\infty} \frac{|\log \log t|}{t\, (\log t)^2} \, dt$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

**Question:** How do I estimate the following integral? $$\int_{2}^{\infty} \frac{|\log \log t|}{t\, (\log t)^2} \, dt$$

**Attempt:** Setting $u=\log t$, we get

$$\int_{2}^{\infty} \frac{|\log \log t|}{t\, (\log t)^2} \, dt = \int_{\log 2}^{\infty} \frac{|\log u|}{u^2}\, du$$ and then I am stuck.

Comment: Can you tell us what you precisely want? An approximate numerical value? How good does it have to be? Whether the integral converges? A closed form?

Comment: How about putting $\log \log t=u$?

Comment: integrate by parts with U=ln(u)

Comment: @Mindlack I want to determine whether the integral converges.

Comment: @user330477: In that case, just use what you know about the growth of logarithms.

Comment: @Mindlack I have problem because of the absolute value. What do we know about growth of logarithms?

Comment: yes, because $\ln(u)=o(u^\epsilon)$ and $O(u^{\epsilon-2})$ is integrable at infinity. for absolute value, you can easily get rid of it by splitting the integral at $u=1$.

Comment: @user330477: the issue is at infinity, and at infinity the integrand is simply $\frac{\log{u}}{u^2}$.

Answer (score 4):

Observe that
\begin{align}
\int^\infty_2 \frac{|\log\log t|}{t(\log t)^2}\ dt = \int^\infty_{\log\log 2} |u|e^{-u}\ du.
\end{align}

You can even evaluate this by hand.

Comment: How do I evaluate the integral on the right, which you got substituting $u=\log \log t$?

Comment: Yes. I used $u=\log\log t$. To evaluate the integral, just break the interval into a piece where $u$ is negative and a piece where $u$ is positive.

Answer (score 0):

Integration by substitution $t=e^u;\;dt=e^u du;\;\log t = u$
$$\int \frac{\log (\log t)}{t \log ^2 t} \, dt=\int\frac{ \log u}{u^2}\,du=-\frac{\log u+1}{u}+C$$

$$\int \frac{\log (\log t)}{t \log ^2 t} \, dt=-\frac{\log (\log t)+1}{\log t}+C$$
$$\int_{2}^{\infty} \frac{|\log \log t|}{t\, (\log t)^2} \, dt=\int_{2}^{e} \left(-\frac{\log \log t}{t\, (\log t)^2}\right) \, dt+\int_{2}^{\infty} \frac{\log \log t}{t\, (\log t)^2} \, dt=$$
$$=\left[\frac{\log (\log t)+1}{\log t}\right]_2^e+\left[-\frac{\log (\log t)+1}{\log t}\right]_e^{\infty}=$$
$$=1-\frac{1+\log (\log 2)}{\log 2}-\underset{m\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\frac{\log (\log m)+1}{\log m}+1=$$
$$=2-\frac{1+\log (\log 2)}{\log 2}\approx 1.086$$